# What happens when a thread that calls Condvar::wait(condvar, some_mutex) is spuriously woken?

Tags: multithreading, rust

If a thread is sleeping, waiting on a notify_one / notify_all call but before this occurs the thread is woken, does the call to wait return or does the thread continue to wait?

I've read the docs (for Condvar::wait) and its unclear to me if it means that a call to wait will return as soon as a thread is woken:

> Note that this function is susceptible to spurious wakeups. Condition variables normally have a boolean predicate associated with them, and the predicate must always be checked each time this function returns to protect against spurious wakeups.

If it is the case that the call to wait returns as soon as the thread is woken, then what  is returned? Since it must return some kind of guard:

```
pub type LockResult<Guard> = Result<Guard, PoisonError<Guard>>;
```

Specific example, in particular, the recv method:

```
pub struct Receiver<T> {
    shared: Arc<Shared<T>>
}

impl<T> Receiver<T> {
    pub fn recv(&self) -> Option<T> {
        let mut inner_mutex_guard:MutexGuard<Inner<T>> = self.shared.inner.lock().unwrap();
        loop {
        
            match inner_mutex_guard.queue.pop_front() {
                Some(t) => return Some(t),
                None => {
                    if inner_mutex_guard.senders == 0 {
                        return None
                    } else {
                        inner_mutex_guard = Condvar::wait(&self.shared.available, inner_mutex_guard).unwrap();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
 
pub struct Inner<T> {
    queue: VecDeque<T>,
    senders: usize
}  

pub struct Shared<T> {
    inner: Mutex<Inner<T>>,
    available: Condvar,
}
```

Comment: it returns the mutex guard and you should check if the condition is met then.  I think [`wait_while`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/std/sync/condvar.rs.html#238) is what you need

Comment: You have to understand that a `CondVar` is more of an optimization. It prevents idle-waiting for a condition. That's why it takes a `Guard`, it's supposed to be combined with a locked value that you want to watch for changes. So if it wakes up, check if the value changed and then go back to `wait`. `wait` is meant to be called in a loop.

Comment: I added a specific example, does this example correctly handle the case of a spurious wake up?

Comment: Yes, your example is correct. Although I would write `inner_mutex_guard = self.shared.available.wait(inner_mutex_guard).unwrap();` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is correct. Although I would write

```rust
inner_mutex_guard = self.shared.available.wait(inner_mutex_guard).unwrap();
```

instead of

```rust
inner_mutex_guard = Condvar::wait(&self.shared.available, inner_mutex_guard).unwrap();
```

If a spurious wakeup happens, your loop will call `pop_front()` again, which will potentially return `None` and enter another `.wait()`.

I understand that you probably got confused by `Condition variables normally have a boolean predicate associated with them`. That's because your boolean predicate is a little hidden ... it is *"Does `.pop_front()` return `Some`"*. Which you do check, as required, whenever a wakeup happens.

The return type of `.wait()` is another `LockGuard`. In order for something to happen, someone else must have the possibility to change the locked value. Therefore, the value must be unlocked while waiting.

As there are several easy-to-miss race conditions in the implementation of `unlock-wait-lock`, it's usually done in a single call. So `.wait()` unlocks the value, waits for the condition to happen, and then locks the value again. That's why it returns a new `LockGuard` ... it is the new locked and potentially changed value.

Although to be honest I'm not sure why they did it that way ... they could as well have done `.wait(&mut LockGuard)` instead of `.wait(LockGuard) -> LockGuard`. But who knows.

**Edit:** I'm pretty sure they return a lock guard because the re-locking could fail; and therefore they don't actually return a `LockGuard` but a `Result<LockGuard>`

**Edit #2:** It cannot be passed in by reference, because during the wait, no `LockGuard` exists. The previous one was dropped, and the new one only exists when the data is locked again. And `LockGuard` does not have an "empty" state (like `None`), so it actually has to be consumed and dropped. Which isn't possible with a reference.

---

### Explanation of `CondVar`

*~ original answer before an example was added ~*

You have to understand that a `CondVar` is more of an optimization. It prevents idle-waiting for a condition. That's why it takes a `Guard`, it's supposed to be combined with a locked value that you want to watch for changes. So if it wakes up, check if the value changed and then go back to `wait`. `wait` is meant to be called in a loop.

Here's an example:

```rust
use std::{
    sync::{Arc, Condvar, Mutex},
    thread::{sleep, JoinHandle},
    time::Duration,
};

struct Counter {
    value: Mutex<u32>,
    condvar: Condvar,
}

fn start_counting_thread(counter: Arc<Counter>) -> JoinHandle<()> {
    std::thread::spawn(move || loop {
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));

        let mut value = counter.value.lock().unwrap();
        *value += 1;
        counter.condvar.notify_all();

        if *value > 15 {
            break;
        }
    })
}

fn main() {
    let counter = Arc::new(Counter {
        value: Mutex::new(0),
        condvar: Condvar::new(),
    });

    let counting_thread = start_counting_thread(counter.clone());

    // Wait until the value more than 10
    let mut value = counter.value.lock().unwrap();
    while *value <= 10 {
        println!("Value is {value}, waiting ...");
        value = counter.condvar.wait(value).unwrap();
    }
    println!("Condition met. Value is now {}.", *value);

    // Unlock value
    drop(value);

    // Wait for counting thread to finish
    counting_thread.join().unwrap();
}
```

```
Value is 0, waiting ...
Value is 1, waiting ...
Value is 2, waiting ...
Value is 3, waiting ...
Value is 4, waiting ...
Value is 5, waiting ...
Value is 6, waiting ...
Value is 7, waiting ...
Value is 8, waiting ...
Value is 9, waiting ...
Value is 10, waiting ...
Condition met. Value is now 11.
```

---

If you don't want to implement the loop manually but instead just wait until a condition is met, use `wait_while`:

```rust
use std::{
    sync::{Arc, Condvar, Mutex},
    thread::{sleep, JoinHandle},
    time::Duration,
};

struct Counter {
    value: Mutex<u32>,
    condvar: Condvar,
}

fn start_counting_thread(counter: Arc<Counter>) -> JoinHandle<()> {
    std::thread::spawn(move || loop {
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));

        let mut value = counter.value.lock().unwrap();
        *value += 1;
        counter.condvar.notify_all();

        if *value > 15 {
            break;
        }
    })
}

fn main() {
    let counter = Arc::new(Counter {
        value: Mutex::new(0),
        condvar: Condvar::new(),
    });

    let counting_thread = start_counting_thread(counter.clone());

    // Wait until the value more than 10
    let mut value = counter.value.lock().unwrap();
    value = counter.condvar.wait_while(value, |val| *val <= 10).unwrap();
    println!("Condition met. Value is now {}.", *value);

    // Unlock value
    drop(value);

    // Wait for counting thread to finish
    counting_thread.join().unwrap();
}
```

```
Condition met. Value is now 11.
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate anwer, it think the reason that the guard is consumed is so that the waiting thread cannot contend with other threads that lock the mutex and notify the waiting thread. Would it be possible for the thread to wake whilst the mutex is locked on another thread or is this guaranteed to not happen even with spurious wake up?

Comment: It returns the locked data, which is only possible if it isn't locked by another thread. The data can never be locked twice simultaneously. If another thread keeps holding the mutex, this thread will be stuck in `.wait` forever.

Comment: @infinitesimallySmart Look at this code and note how it only wakes up every two numbers: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=180583f2c37b9b793b1bab6dff0b73d8